# git submodule with environment

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have this `.gitsubmodule`:

```
[submodule "modules/some-utils"]
    path = modules/some-utils
    url = ../some-utils.git
    branch = main
```

With that, I will always checkout to `main` each time that I update a the submodule.

What I need is to manage 3 different branches for different environments. I need something like:

```
[submodule "modules/some-utils"]
    path = modules/some-utils
    url = ../some-utils.git
    branch = $ENVIRONMENT
```

Where `$ENVIRONMENT` be a value taken directly from an external file, for instance a `.env` file.

Is that possible?

Comment: What is your `$ENVIRONMENT`, or how you will detect that you are on the specific environment? Is it something for pipeline, or for different machines?

Comment: that my question, I need something like that, I wonder is there a way to define a variable taken from another file like a `.env`

Answer (score 0):

Git does not do what you want "out of the box".

Git is, however, a *set of tools* rather than a "solution".<sup>1</sup>  The good news is that, as a tool-set, Git is *programmable*.

The `branch = main` you can set in a `.gitmodules` file is not used directly *except* when you run `git submodule update` with certain options.  When you *do* use those options, you can *first* run *your own* `git config` commands.  See the description of the `--remote` flag to `git submodule update` in [the `git submodule` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

Since `submodule.modules/some-utils.branch` is not even *used* if you first override it here, it won't matter that you can't set it to a variable name.  Just set up your build process to override it *before* running `git submodule update --remote`.

---

<sup>1</sup>For more on the distinction, see [this article](https://www.business2community.com/strategy/the-difference-between-a-tool-and-a-solution-02225199).